# url routing in codeigniter according to the type and name

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I have read the url routing topic in user guide of the CI.

I am doing this for the first time so may I misunderstood some technique so feel free to point it out.

I am working on a creating a custom url according the product. 
Currently I am getting a single product detail by Id.

I have use this anchor tag for sending a id to the controller.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url("product_controller/getSingle_product_function/{$value->product_id}"); ?>">
```

so my url is : `myWebsite/product_controller/getSingle_product_function/1`

What I want in the url is : `myWebsite/product_name-product_type/1`

for getting this url I have to create a route at the routes.php, but the propblem is how do I get my product name and type to the routes.php or how do i get that.

```
$route['product_name-product_type/1'] = "product_controller/getSingle_product_function/1";
```

Updated Work:

Now After seeing some answers I have created an anchor which look like below,

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url("product_controller/getSingle_product_function/product_name/product_type/produt_id"); ?>">
```

so the url before route : www.website.com/controller/function/xyz-name/abc-type/1

& then I created a root,

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = "product_controller/product_function/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/$1";
```

Final Url After route : www.website.com/xyz-name/abc-type/1

Now the only question is that is my final route is correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this..

```
$route['product_name-product_type/(:num)'] = "product_controller/getSingle_product_function/$1";
```

> `(:num)` is a wildcard that match a segment containing only numbers.

Comment: Sir how can i get my product_name and type at url? it is not static every product has different name and type. so how to do it for this type of url.

Comment: just get `id` of product first from `uri` using `$id = $this->uri->segment(2)` then perform DB query to get product name.

Comment: i get it sir,  i have already get the product detail , but i think you telling me that i have to put a name and type in the anchor and then i get. ??

Comment: Why you need to get product name form id.You can use name instead of id in url.

Comment: i get it sir , i get  all detail of product by Id but for the SEO i want to make my url more perfect or what i say more proper so that's way i want the product name and type in url

Comment: `$id = $this->uri->segment(2)` will give current product id.Then from this id make database query and get all the details.

Comment: You are correct sir, but may be i am not good enough to understand or i did not explain my question properly because what you are suggesting is what i already get. I just want the url to be proper.

Comment: OK i got your problem you also need to pass product name type in controller's function.

Comment: ok so i do it like this is it correct :   <a href="<?php echo base_url("product_controller/getSingle_product_function/{$value->product_Name}-{$value->product_type}/{$value->product_id}"); ?>">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138195/discussion-between-hek-mat-and-user3631086).

Comment: then change `(:num)` to `(:any)`.

Comment: Sir i have created an route can you tell me is it follow the basic routeing rule?  @users7247090

Comment: try like `$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = "product_controller/product_function/$1/$2/$3/$4";
`

Comment: It's working sir, thanks for the help sir, really made my day sir thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
$route['(:any)/(:num)'] = 'product_controller/getSingle_product_function/$1/$2';
```

Just remember that this has to be lower in the routes file. I would normally put this right above the default_controller.

```
public function getSingle_product_function($product_details, $product_id) {
    $product = explode('-', $product_details);
    $name = $product[0];
    $type = $product[1];
}
```

The order would be passed into the controller function in the order of the $1/$2.

Comment: sir  I have updated my question just tell me that is my created route is correct or not?

Comment: $route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = "product_controller/product_function/$1/$2/$3/$4";